# Conditional Where clause: Any way to write except dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my query which is not compiling:

```
Select 1 from dbo.EmailAddresses e
    Inner Join Users u On e.UserID = u.UserID
        Where LOWER(EmailAddress) = @EmailAddress               
        And
    Case When @For = 1 Then e.JurisdictionID IS NOT NULL  When @For = 2 Then e.AccountID IS NOT NULL  End
```

Can anybody tell me a way to write this query without dynamic query i.e building a query in string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select 1 from dbo.EmailAddresses e
    Inner Join Users u On e.UserID = u.UserID
        Where LOWER(EmailAddress) = @EmailAddress               
        And (
            (@For = 1 AND e.JurisdictionID IS NOT NULL) OR
            (@For = 2 AND e.AccountID IS NOT NULL)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try 
Easy and one way to try out with out case when ..

```
Select 1 from dbo.EmailAddresses e 

    Inner Join Users u On e.UserID = u.UserID 
        Where LOWER(EmailAddress) = @EmailAddress                        
And  (   (@For = 1 and e.JurisdictionID IS NOT NULL)
        or ( @For = 2 and e.AccountID IS NOT NULL  ))
```